# Pandas Series apply function that returns multiple rows and adds a second level to the index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a function that I apply to a Pandas Series elementwise, i.e. a `map`.  That function returns multiple values (which I am returning as another Series at the moment, but can be a list instead).  I want the result to be a new Series object where each value is added as another row and a new level added to the index, so if the original Series had one level index, the output would have a MultiIndex with two levels. Sounds simple enough, but I can find a clear way of doing that. Thank you

For example, this Series

[image]

and this function

`lambda x: pd.Series([10,20,30]) if x==2 else pd.Series([40,50])`

should come out as

[image]

I can get there with `melt` and `dropna` etc, but there must be a more straightforward way of doing this, like some parametr to `apply()` or something, but I can't seem to find one.

Thank you

**Add 1**

This seems to be the cleanest way so far, just need to find a way of adding a second index name too....

`s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.iloc[0]))`

**Add 2**

Returning a list instead of a Series in the function call and then transforming the result as

`pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), index=s.index).stack()`

seem to be much faster than returning a Series in each function call.

Comment: post a testable input and the expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Thank you for taking time to read and comment on my post. Please see the updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `stack` + `rename_axis` functions:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], name='index_0')  # sample series
s = (s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([10,20,30]) if x==2 else pd.Series([40,50]))
      .stack().rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'], axis=0))
```

---

```
index_0  index_1
0        0          40.0
         1          50.0
1        0          10.0
         1          20.0
         2          30.0
2        0          40.0
         1          50.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Another option is `s.groupby(level=0).apply(...)` but instead of `x.iloc[0]==2` use `x.values[0]==2`, it should evaluate faster:

```
(s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([10,20,30]) 
   if x.values[0] == 2 else pd.Series([40,50]))
  .rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'], axis=0))
```

Comment: Thank you.  A little better than what I had with `dropna`, `melt`, `reset_index` and `set_idex`  )) ...  but still not as clean as jus passing a parameter to `apply`...  I am thinking maybe `groupby` can do it?....

Comment: Doing `groupby(level=0)` and calling `apply` on each element automatically returns a result with two index levels.

Comment: @Confounded, you may try `(s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([10,20,30]) if (x==2).all() else pd.Series([4
     ...: 0,50])).rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'], axis=0))` - but it runs slower

Comment: @Confounded, see my note regarding `s.groupby(level=0) ...` alternative

Comment: Thank you.  I am also finding that creating Series in each call takes a bit of time.  Maybe there is a better faster way of returning a list in the function call and then transforming?

Comment: It seem that returning a list and then doing `pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), index=subset.index).stack()` is much faster.

Comment: @Confounded, great catch! Thanks for the observation

Comment: @Confounded but still slower than `concat`, I added a comparison in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I would just use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), since the logic is, in fact, a concatenation of Series:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], name='index_0')

out = pd.concat(dict(enumerate(pd.Series([40, 50]) if x==2
                               else pd.Series([10,20,30])
                               for x in s))
                ).rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'])
```

Or with a function:

```
myfunc = lambda x: pd.Series([10,20,30]) if x==2 else pd.Series([40,50])
def concat(s, f=myfunc):
    return pd.concat(dict(enumerate(myfunc(x) for x in s))
                    ).rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'])
```

Output:

```
index_0  index_1
0        0          10
         1          20
         2          30
1        0          40
         1          50
2        0          10
         1          20
         2          30
dtype: int64
```

For fun, an alternative using a 2D intermediate:

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({True: [40, 50], False: [10, 20, 30]},
                        orient='index')
   .reindex(s.eq(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
   .stack().rename_axis(['index_0', 'index_1'])
)
```

##### timing of approaches

`groupby_apply2` is `s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.iloc[0]))`

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, but I think it suffers from being less easy to read/understand (although it might be just due to my lack of experience).  Thank you, nevertheless.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the call to `enumerate` inside `dict` creates keys `0, 1, 2` which are then used for the outer 'index_0' values, but this will only work for this toy example as in the real world prolem the outer index is coming from the original Series and needs to be preserved in the final output.  I guess this can be addressed by assigning `s.index` somewhere.

Comment: @Confounded you can always use a dictionary comprehension instead of `enumerate` and assign whichever key is wanted. Update the example and I'll update the answer.